# Installing C API for Tensorflow on Macbook M1

Tags: c, tensorflow, go, apple-m1, c-api

I am trying to install C API of tensorflow on Macbook M1 to execute it in Go. I followed this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c#macos) by tensorflow developers but got stuck when running the `hello_tf.c` file with this command `gcc hello_tf.c -ltensorflow -o hello_tf`.

This is `hello_tf.c` file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello from TensorFlow C library version %s\n", TF_Version());
  return 0;
}
```

And this is the error log:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libtensorflow.2.7.0.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_TF_Version", referenced from:
      _main in hello_tf-6f1778.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation
```

Any suggestions on how to get the compilation fixed?

Comment: This error is common in Mac M1 as seen in the issues reported on Apple developer forum. The best answer found which worked for many was saving your project before running it. Do follow the same to get rid of the error.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on my Mac M2 running Sonoma 14.3.1. @TF_Chinmay could you elaborate on your solution or share a link to one?